# WordPress Elementor (Free version) with a Max Mega Menu

Tags: wordpress, elementor, megamenu, wp-mega-menu

I am trying to create a mega menu by using **Max Mega Menu**. I have created a section template with elementor **free version**. But when i am trying to attach this section to the menu item, i dont see the **Elementor Library** option inside the dropdown. I am new to wordpress and elementor. I am in practicing phase.

I would be grateful if someone would help me out.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I hope this documentation will help you.

https://www.megamenu.com/documentation/elementor/

Thank You